# How to validate if an attribute belongs to a certain user

Tags: laravel, validation

Hy guys I am trying to validate if the category, belongs to a certain user, I have tryed this but I getting an error when I enter a non existing value. What I tryed:

```
'category' => ['nullable','exists:categories,id', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {


    $category = Category::where('id', $value)->first();

    if($category->vcard!= $this->vcard->phone_number)
    {
       $fail('The selected category is invalid.');
    }
}]
```

So this works when I entered a valid category, but if I entered a wrong categry, for example category id 100000 that doesnt exists, throws me this error, on postman:

[image]

I thought that the `'exists:categories,id'` will fix me, the non existing ids.

Works:

```
{
 "payment_reference": "a1@mail.com",
 "payment_type": "PAYPAL",
 "type": "D",
 "value": 10,
 "description": "Teste",
 "category": 500
}
```

Not working:

```
{
 "payment_reference": "a1@mail.com",
 "payment_type": "PAYPAL",
 "type": "D",
 "value": 10,
 "description": "Teste",
 "category": 1000000
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to fix this would be to check if `$category` is null or not:

```
if($category && $category->vcard != $this->vcard->phone_number) {
   $fail('The selected category is invalid.');
}
```

When using `find` or `first` with Eloquent, the model will be returned if it exists and `null` will be returned if it doesn't.

---

Alternatively, you could use the [bail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure) validation rule for `category`:

```
'category' => [
    'bail',
    'nullable',
    'exists:categories,id',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        $category = Category::where('id', $value)->first();

        if ($category->vcard != $this->vcard->phone_number) {
            $fail('The selected category is invalid.');
        }
    },
],
```

This will mean that if the `exists` rule fails the closure won't even be executed.

Comment: Worked really well 'bail', I thought that laravel did it by fault (failing on first validation rule)